# How to recreate the opera gx button in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wish to make buttons just like the navigation ones in opera gx new tab or firefox new tab in asp.net for my web site

```
background-origin: content-box;
background-position: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I tried something like this but I think is much deeper than that...

Answer (score 0):

your css codes  have no relationship with the color ,and i'm not sure which color you do want,but I could give you some suggetions to get the color you want .

You could copy the img to the default Paint App of windows and get the RGB color:

[image]

You could adjust the value until you got the value you want

I tried as below:

```
<style>    
input{        
width: 230px;        
height: 80px;        
background-origin: content-box ;        
background-position: 50% ;        
background-repeat: no-repeat ;        
background-size: cover ;        
background-color:rgb(28,23,38);        
border-color:rgb(250,30,78);        
border-style:solid;                
color:rgb(250,30,78);        
font-size:40px;          
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="but"/>
```

the button:

[image]